# After package name change the project still uses old package name for launching the application

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, package-name

I changed the package name of android application recently.

The package name of the changed project is correct.

I [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/730807) this approach for package name changing.

I made sure the package-name change is the recent one in Manifest.

But while launching the application it uses *old package name* other than that everything is ok.

I tired restarting the android studio and my machine.Nothing works.

Here is the error message I got

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.test.old/com1.test1.new.LoginActivity } Error type 3 Error:
>   Activity class {com.test.old/com1.test1.new.LoginActivity} does not
>   exist.

Comment: Change package name in build.gradle file. It will work.

Comment: In my case there was no package name there.so I added it and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set the *new package name* as value to *applicationId* key in the *build.gradle* and it solved my problem

### Build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com1.test1.new"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
```

Comment: I did not have the applicationId set in the build.gradle, so I am assuming that Android Studio was using a default. But setting the value fixed as stated in this answer.